# Arrays appended to a list , are they soft copies

Tags: python, arrays

I was wondering how to append an array to a list , in such a way that if i edit the array elsewhere in my code, the changes reflect in my list.

Comment: Do you mean put the array itself into a list, or do you mean put the contents of the array into a list?

Comment: You can add the whole array to a list as **one** item. But it you append the items in the array to a list one by one all relations to the array are lost.

Comment: Is there any way to keep it so that i append more than one array, and changing the original arrays , changes the values in the list?

Comment: I am appending whole arrays, but their values in the list dont change when i update the original arrays??

Comment: Please provide more clarity in this question with some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try it yourself, in 1min:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [x, [4, 5, 6]]
x[0] = 0
print(y)
```

> [[0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: What happens if i use the y.append(x)...from my experiments x[0]=0 doesnt change it

Comment: Just tried it:
`x = [1, 2, 3]`
`y = [[4, 5, 6]]`
`y.append(x)`
`x[0] = 0`
`print(y)`
`[[4, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3]]`

Comment: i tried this ```list=[]
n=np.ones((2,1))
for y in range(5):
    x=y*n
    list.append(x)

print(list)
x=x*2
print(list)
print('x=',x)
``` and the value of x printed was not equivalent to the valus in the last array in the list.

Comment: got this :
(base) C:\Users\Link\Desktop\new>python y.py
[array([[0.],
       [0.]]), array([[1.],
       [1.]]), array([[2.],
       [2.]]), array([[3.],
       [3.]]), array([[4.],
       [4.]])]
[array([[0.],
       [0.]]), array([[1.],
       [1.]]), array([[2.],
       [2.]]), array([[3.],
       [3.]]), array([[4.],
       [4.]])]
x= [[8.]
 [8.]]

(base) C:\Users\Link\Desktop\new>

(base) C:\Users\Link\Desktop\new>

Comment: Because you are realocating `x` when you do `x = x * 2`. Do `x *= 2` instead.

Comment: does x=np.concatenate(x,y) and all the other variants reallocate?And how would one go around this.

Comment: It cannot work for concatenation, if you are seeking a way to go around this, I would suggest you to open another question as this thread is getting long.